# Karate: is there a way to apply functions against Examples: variables?

Tags: karate

I have a karate test which passes:

```
Feature:  Armstrong numbers

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * configure lowerCaseResponseHeaders = true

  Scenario Outline: Find Armstrong numbers in the range from <start> to <end> are <result>
    Given path '/armstrongs'
    And param start = <start>
    And param end = <end>
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match header content-type contains 'application/json'
    And match header content-type contains 'charset=utf-8'
    And match response == {numbers:<result>, start:<start>, end:<end>, count: <count>, type:Armstrong}
    Examples:
      | start | end    | result                | count
      | 1     | 10     | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   | 9
      | 100   | 1000   | [153, 370, 371, 407]  | 4
      | 90000 | 100000 | [92727, 93084]        | 2
```

However, what I would like to do is not have the count variable from the Examples: section and just derive the count from the length of the  variable this way:

```
Feature:  Armstrong numbers

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * configure lowerCaseResponseHeaders = true

  Scenario Outline: Find Armstrong numbers in the range from <start> to <end> are <result>
    Given path '/armstrongs'
    And param start = <start>
    And param end = <end>
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match header content-type contains 'application/json'
    And match header content-type contains 'charset=utf-8'
    And match response == {numbers:<result>, start:<start>, end:<end>, count: <result>.length, type:Armstrong}
    Examples:
      | start | end    | result
      | 1     | 10     | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      | 100   | 1000   | [153, 370, 371, 407]
      | 90000 | 100000 | [92727, 93084]
```

When I try this, I get an error:

```
Armstrong.feature:15 - net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException: Unexpected token . at position 72.
```

and the test fails.

Is there a way to apply functions against Examples: variables, such as .length, to get the expected results and have the test pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change:

```
And def result = <result>
And match response == {numbers: '#(result)', start: <start>, end: <end>, count: '#(result.length)', type: 'Armstrong' }
```

Comment: How would the solution change if  <result> above was a JSON object such as {a:1, b:2, c:3} and not an array?    I tried count: '#(Object.keys(result).length)' --- which does not work.   Seems to work fine as valid javascript but not in karate.

Comment: @joe you can ask a new question